# How to define a smaller sized object from a bigger sized object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, data-structures, filter

Data structure I'm working with:

```
this.theDataStructureIHave = [
  {
    "1304": {
      "id": 6458,
      "data": "Data1",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1305": {
      "id": 6459,
      "data": "Data2",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1306": {
      "id": 6460,
      "data": "Data3",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1307": {
      "id": 6461,
      "data": "1227",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1308": {
      "id": 6462,
      "data": "12256",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "header": null,
    "id": 500
  },
  {
    "1304": {
      "id": 6463,
      "data": "Data4",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1305": {
      "id": 6464,
      "data": "Data5",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1306": {
      "id": 6465,
      "data": "Data6",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1307": {
      "id": 6466,
      "data": "3574",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1308": {
      "id": 6467,
      "data": "25824",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "header": null,
    "id": 501
  },
  {
    "1304": {
      "id": 6468,
      "data": "Data7",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1305": {
      "id": 6469,
      "data": "Data8",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:39",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:39"
    },
    "1306": {
      "id": 6470,
      "data": "Data9",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:39",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:39"
    },
    "1307": {
      "id": 6471,
      "data": "3061",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:39",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:39"
    },
    "1308": {
      "id": 6472,
      "data": "26696",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:39",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:39"
    },
    "header": null,
    "id": 502
  }
]
```

Data structure I want to achieve:

```
this.theResultIWant = [
  {
    "1304": {
      "id": 6458,
      "data": "Data1",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1306": {
      "id": 6460,
      "data": "Data3",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    }
  },
  {
    "1304": {
      "id": 6463,
      "data": "Data4",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1306": {
      "id": 6465,
      "data": "Data6",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    }
  },
  {
    "1304": {
      "id": 6468,
      "data": "Data7",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1306": {
      "id": 6470,
      "data": "Data9",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:39",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:39"
    },
  }
]
```

In summary I have an array with two objects and inside those objects are more objects (this.theDataStructureIHave).

Starting with that data structure I want to create a new array of objects which essentially contains certain elements from this.theDataStructureIHave.

Also here I have an array of numbers: [1304, 1306]. Say this is assigned to the variable arrayOfNumbers = [1304, 1306]

The end result I want then is to filter through this.theDataStructureIHave and retrieve the objects where the index is equal to 1304 and 1306. arrayOfNumbers is a dynamic value (this is just an example), which looks like this in code:

```
this.arrayOfNumbers = this.someObject.columns.map(Number);
```

Is there a way I can achieve this and get this.theResultIWant from this.theDataStructureIHave dynamically? Without hardcoding values?

Please also see the bottom of the codepen for the data structure I'm trying to achieve called this.theResultIWant

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code itself, not just a link to a codepen. If you want to make a runnable example, use a stack snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware that this solution is not safe depending on the input. It won't throw an exception if the input data is incorrect.

How it works:

1. We are mapping over theDataStructureIHave, i.e. changing every outerObject in this array into something else
2. `Object.entries(outerObject)` gives us pairs of keys and values of this object (something like `[[key1, value1], [key2, value2], [key3, value3]]`)
3. We `filter` those keys based on whether they are included in the `arrayOfNumbers`. Please note that the array has integers and the object has keys as strings, hence the need for `parseInt`. If you are confused by `([key, _])` - it's an array destructuring, i.e. it takes `[key, val]` array and gives us separately `key` and separately `value` (that I am not using, so I named it `_`), otherwise we would use something like `(keyValuePair)` and then reference key as `keyValuePair[0]`
4. `Object.fromEntries(...)` constructs back an object based on key/value pairs

```js
const theDataStructureIHave = [{
    "1304": {
      "id": 6458,
      "data": "Data1",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1305": {
      "id": 6459,
      "data": "Data2",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1306": {
      "id": 6460,
      "data": "Data3",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1307": {
      "id": 6461,
      "data": "1227",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1308": {
      "id": 6462,
      "data": "12256",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "header": null,
    "id": 500
  },
  {
    "1304": {
      "id": 6463,
      "data": "Data4",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1305": {
      "id": 6464,
      "data": "Data5",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1306": {
      "id": 6465,
      "data": "Data6",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1307": {
      "id": 6466,
      "data": "3574",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1308": {
      "id": 6467,
      "data": "25824",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "header": null,
    "id": 501
  },
  {
    "1304": {
      "id": 6468,
      "data": "Data7",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:38"
    },
    "1305": {
      "id": 6469,
      "data": "Data8",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:39",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:39"
    },
    "1306": {
      "id": 6470,
      "data": "Data9",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:39",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:39"
    },
    "1307": {
      "id": 6471,
      "data": "3061",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:39",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:39"
    },
    "1308": {
      "id": 6472,
      "data": "26696",
      "created_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:39",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-20 23:16:39"
    },
    "header": null,
    "id": 502
  }
]

const arrayOfNumbers = [1304, 1306];

const result = theDataStructureIHave.map(outerObject =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(outerObject).filter(([key, _]) => arrayOfNumbers.includes(parseInt(key))))
);

console.log(result)
```